# How to properly use the `language` field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages, polyglossia

I am using biblatex (with biber) and setting the `language` field in entries in my `.bib` file. Oddly, the language is not interpreted as a localisation key, as it apparently ought to be. (I am using polyglossia for language support and localisation.)

I get output like the following.

```
Hume, D., 1777. An enquiry concerning human understanding. british.
```

(The above presumes I set `language = {british}`. If I set `language = {en-GB}`, then the corresponding text appears instead in the output document.)

Am I missing something here?

As a side point, I would be grateful if anyone can recommend how to *not* print the language in the bibliography as long as it is one of the document languages (i.e., the one of the "default" or "other" languages).

#### Minimum reproducible example

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{author00,
    title = {{A Title}},
    publisher = {Alpha},
    year = {2008},
    editor = {Author, A},
    address = {London},
    language = {english},
}
@book{buthor00,
    title = {{B Title}},
    publisher = {Bravo},
    year = {1990},
    author = {Buthor, B},
    address = {New York},
    language = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[backend = biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

    \citeauthor{author00} has written \textcite{author00}.
    \citeauthor{buthor00} has written \textcite{buthor00}.
    
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the duplicate: `langid = {english}` instead of `language = {english}` works for your MWE.

Comment: @Marijn That's not the issue I'm afraid. I'll post the answer presently.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I ended up with, after some kind advice from @UlrikeFischer on the chat here.

The main issue was that I was doing `\setdefaultlanguage{british}` but not `\setmainlanguage{british}`, so localisation was not taking effect. Silly me!

```latex
% Do not mention language of an entry if it is in the same or another variety of English.
% Copied from `tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx` in the biblatex package, and adjusted accordingly.
% This solves the "side point" in my question.
\DeclareRedundantLanguages{british}{english,american,british,canadian,australian,newzealand,USenglish,UKenglish}

% Define localisation strings for the 'british' language.
% This is just an example, since due to the above "redundant languages" setting, this is superfluous, though it would not be if you did, e.g., `\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{...}`.
\NewBibliographyString{langbritish}
\NewBibliographyString{frombritish}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    langbritish = {British},
    frombritish = {from the British},
}
```